# closeOnCompletion doesn't work properly in MySQL JDBC 5.1.32

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a snippet like this:

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table_A");

statement.closeOnCompletion();
System.out.println(statement.isCloseOnCompletion());

rs.close();
System.out.println(statement.isClosed());
```

After closeOnCompletion is invoked, I expect the statement to be closed, as its result set is closed. However, it just shows "false" when checking statement.isClosed().

Did I misunderstand the jdk doc? as it says: closeOnCompletion() Specifies that this Statement will be closed when all its dependent result sets are closed.

===========================
Update:
It turns out to be my carelessness. The last statement actually returns a result of expected "true". So it's no longer an issue

Comment: Don't you have to call `.closeOnCompletion()` *before* `.executeQuery()`?

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake when checking the result in my real code. It actually shows "true" when checkin statement.isClosed()

Answer (score 2):

Since Statement is depend on result I would suggest this

```
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table_A");

rs.close();
statement.close();  
System.out.println(statement.isClosed());
```

This is applicable if your ultimate want is to close statement, if your question is why statement is not closing even when called onexit, then better to refer javadocs.